# Randomly assign an image a value, then pass an animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm looking to create an array with all my images in, I then want to assign a random image a value between 1 - 10. The value it ends up with will be a timed countdown in seconds until my Jquery animation is run. The code will then loop over and over, until the person leaves that page.

So I'm new to Jquery but I tried my best to get my head around so this is my image array, and my random selector;

```
var iconImgs = new Array('star','coffee','picture','code');
var max = iconImgs.length;
var num = Math.floor((Math.random() * max));
```

Then I need to select a random time between 1 - 10;

```
Math.floor((Math.random()*10)+1);
```

This is the hard bit I need to take the image that was selected and the random time put those together and then run my animation (Note I DON'T want it to run onenter but its the only way I got it to work).

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(".icon").mouseenter(function () {
    $(this).effect("bounce", {
        times: 1
    }, 400);
    });
});
```

I made a JSFiddle testing area - http://jsfiddle.net/UQTY2/167/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Try this

```
var iconImgs = new Array('star','coffee','picture','code');
var max = iconImgs.length;
var times = Math.floor((Math.random()*10)+1);

$(document).ready(function () {

    setInterval(function () {
        var num = Math.floor((Math.random() * max));

        $("."+iconImgs[num]+"-icon").effect("bounce", {
            times: times
        }, 400);
    }, 400);

});
```

JSFIDDLE:
http://jsfiddle.net/UQTY2/168/

Answer (score 1):

First make sure your storing the random times in a variable:

```
var times=Math.floor((Math.random()*10)+1);
```

Then in your function, instead of `mouseenter` just fire the effect:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("."+iconImgs[num]+"-icon").effect("bounce", {
        times: times
    }, 400);
});
```

Comment: Thanks will do, I shall change that